# Trouble getting sockets to connect in windows7 64bit

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-7, 64-bit

Hey. I've been searching around for a solution to this problem with no luck. I was wondering if this is a known issue when switching socket code from WinXP 32 bit to Win7 64 bit. I have a fairly simple socket routine which works fine in WinXP 32bit, but the socket.connect call is throwing the exception "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:48000"

I've added an exception to the win7 firewall for the program, and doubled checked to make sure the rule it added was allowing all ports.

The code I use to setup these simple sockets is as follows:

**Listening Socket:**

```
byte[] bytes = new Byte[8192];
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 48000);

_ListenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

try
{
    _ListenerSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
    _ListenerSocket.Listen(1000);

    while (_Running)
    {
        _ListenerSync.Reset();
        _ListenerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _ListenerSocket);
        _ListenerSync.WaitOne();
    }

    _ListenerSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _ListenerSocket.Close();
}
```

**Connecting Socket:**

```
IPAddress _IP;
IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1", out _IP)
Socket tTarget = null;

if (tTarget == null)
{
    tTarget = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}

tTarget.Connect(_IP, 48000);
_Connected = true;
byte[] tBuffer = new byte[8192];
string tRecvBuff = "";

while (_Connected)
{
    int tRecv = tTarget.Receive(tBuffer);
    //{ does stuff here }
}
```

Seems like everything works until tTarget.Connect(), where it pauses for a second and then throws the exception listed above. AcceptCallback is never called.

Thanks.

Comment: Try running netstat -ab -p tcp | find /i "Listening" to see if you program is actually listening on that port.

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave good call. something doesn't look right there. under netstat -a it is listed as "TCP [::1]:48000 compname:0 LISTENING", I'm not quite sure what that means though.

Comment: Seems like IPV6 is enabled on your loopback adapter try disabling it and test your code. If it works then you can modify your code to account for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment your listening on IPV6. Instead of

```
ipHostInfo.AddressList[0]
```

try

```
ipHostInfo.AddressList.ToList().Find(p=>p.AddressFamily==AddressFamily.InterNetw‌​ork);
```

Comment: I tried this and I am receiving `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily' and 'string'`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like AddressFamily is an enum, so try ipHostInfo.AddressList.ToList().Find(p=>p.AddressFamily==AddressFamily.InterNetwork);