# invalid argument passed to socket listener

Tags: c#, sockets

I've been receiving this error continuously and I believe I narrowed down my issue to being that I'm [using a 32-bit](http://inthehand.com/forums/t/5313.aspx) listener on a 64-bit machine. Is there any way to get this to run on a 64-bit system?

[image]

```
18      Socket sListener;
...
34          permission = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Tcp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts);

36          //Listening Socket object
37          sListener = null;

39          //Ensure the code has permission to access the Socket
40          permission.Demand();

42          IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
43          IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[2];
44          ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 4510);

46          sListener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
...
71      sListener.Listen(10);
72
73      //Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt
74      AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
75      sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);
```

I tried to follow the code in this [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543718/trouble-getting-sockets-to-connect-in-windows7-64bit) question, but it gave me the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily' and 'string'

Comment: in the code i dont find anything relevant to `==`

Comment: For the error in the code you got from the related question, AddressFamily is an enum.  Try `==AddressFamily.InterNetwork` instead of `=="InterNetwork"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the [Socket Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx), before a Socket can [Listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx) at a port.

As per MSDN :

> Use the Bind method if you need to use a specific local endpoint. You
>   must call Bind before you can call the Listen method. You do not need
>   to call Bind before using the Connect method unless you need to use a
>   specific local endpoint. You can use the Bind method on both
>   connectionless and connection-oriented protocols.
>
> Before calling Bind, you must first create the local IPEndPoint from
>   which you intend to communicate data. If you do not care which local
>   address is assigned, you can create an IPEndPoint using IPAddress.Any
>   as the address parameter, and the underlying service provider will
>   assign the most appropriate network address. This might help simplify
>   your application if you have multiple network interfaces. If you do
>   not care which local port is used, you can create an IPEndPoint using
>   0 for the port number. In this case, the service provider will assign
>   an available port number between 1024 and 5000.

```
70:    sListen.Bind(your IP end point)
71:    sListener.Listen(10);
```

---

P.S. : Always use a value greater then 4000 for listening port!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `MaxConnections` property as discussed in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx)?

That documentation also describes how to check the `ErrorCode` for more detailed information. Perhaps you should explore that option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following sample will help you too.

```
Socket clientSocket;
System.Net.IPEndPoint clientEndPoint;
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream networkStream;
IAsyncResult beginAcceptAsyncResult;
System.Threading.WaitHandle []waitHandleArray;
int waitHandleSignalled;

System.Net.IPEndPoint listenEndpoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 45000); //make sure port is free (check with cmd: netstat -an)
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener listener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(listenEndpoint);

waitHandleArray = new System.Threading.WaitHandle[1];

listener.Start();

do
{
    try
    beginAcceptAsyncResult = listener.BeginAcceptSocket(null, null);
    waitHandleArray[0] = beginAcceptAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle;
    waitHandleSignalled = System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandleArray);

    if (waitHandleSignalled != 0)
    {
        clientSocket = _TCPListener.EndAcceptSocket(BeginAcceptAsyncResult);

        clientEndPoint = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint as System.Net.IPEndPoint;

        networkStream = new System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream(clientSocket, true);

        //do more with NetworkStream...
    }
}
//...
//...
```